# Did the tribal chief curse literally or figuratively?

Tags: plot-explanation, jungle-cruise

In [Jungle Cruise (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0870154/), Aguirre is cursed by thr tribal chief for the massacre.

> He is never to lose sight of the river otherwise the jungle would take them back.

Does this mean that the Jungle would literally **pull** them back to where river water is?

Comment: Can downvoter please explain the reason ? Or is it just a revenge downvote ?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the Jungle would literally pull them back to where river water is?

### Yes

We actually see this happening during his first encounter with Frank and Lily.

He chases Lily into the jungle to reclaim the arrowhead but get's too far away and the we actually see the jungle pull him back to the river.

We also see it when Frank is telling Aguirre's story...

[image]